# Stop ViewController from intercepting touches

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, touch

I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 5 with Swift to make a game. I am using touch recognisers (e.g touchesBegan, touchesEnded), and when the game ends, a new view is shown. However, the first view controller is still receiving touches and trying to perform the methods again.

How can i stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried the following. Do it when your game ends. -

```
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```